# How can I stop Outlook 2013 resizing images inserted into an HTML email?

Tags: windows, images, microsoft-outlook-2010, dpi

(using: Windows 8.1 [running at 125% DPI], Outlook 2013, Exchange 2007 )

Hi

I have a problem getting my designs which I am creating on Outlook emails to come out correctly if I have changed the Window DPI setting to 125% (i.e. 120 DPI).

What happens is the moment that I insert an image into the body of an email in Outlook the image is resized (physically made larger by 25%, by blurring in my case). In some instances this resizing only happens the moment you press Send.

Either way what the recipient sees is an enlarged, blurred image. Nightmare.

At present the ONLY answer seems to be to change the Windows DPI to 96DPI. However one is forced to log out of Windows for this to take effect. However the Windows text on any moderately high res screen is painfully small and I am then soon forced by hurting eyes to change it back again which involves logging out and in again.

I have tried creating images of 120 DPI (difficult but possible) however this does not seem to work.

Gmail is out of the question for several reasons.

I have tried Thunderbird but it too enlarger images when displayed and also the only way to get it to work with Exchange is to install a plugin. I have use ExQillia but that will blow up in 60 days and thereafter it costs $10 which is not acceptable.

If any one knows a way to stop Outlook 2013 from re-sizing please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: There is no option called "ClearType" nor "Text Tuner" visible in Control Panel. However if I type "ClearType" into Windows search behind the Start Button (bottom left of screen) an option called "Adjust ClearType Text" appears. Yes, I am already using ClearType if that's what you mean. However it does not include any direct mechanism to change the text size.

If all else fails I shall have to what you suggest but I have tried changing System Font before and it's extremely messy as almost every application will need to be adjusted and this will be painful even if possible.

Comment: Yes I have already done the adjusting too. Searching for "System Fonts" in Control Panel finds nothing on my Win 7 (x64) PC.

Comment: I have experimented with changing the Windows appearance in setting by setting but ultimately it's too fiddly and never really works very well. 
OK for simplicity I have re-framed the question. OP

Comment: Are you taking a screenshot as part of your process by any chance? I don't see how any email client would resize an image but if you're taking a screenshot and then pasting it into the email, the image would be blurry due to the fact that Windows is set to stretch out everything shown on your screen by 125%. Also, you have your metrics backwards; increasing the sizing of objects on screen to 125% lowers your DPI. DPI is normally 72 so it would be closer to 60 if you've chosen 125% display sizing.